# App Engine - is it mandatory to use warmup request to use min_instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, djangoappengine

I currently use app engine standard environment with django. I want to have automatic scaling and always have at least one instance running.

Consulting the documentation it says that to use `min_instances` it is recommended to have `warm up requests` enabled.

My question is: is this mandatory? Is there no way to always have an active instance without using `warm up requests`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably more of a question for Google engineers.  But, I think that they are required.  The docs don't say "recommended"; They say "must":

[image]

Imagine if your instances shut down because of a server reboot.  The `warmup` request gets them running again. A `start` request would also do the trick, but after some delay.  It could be that Google depends on sending `warmup` requests after reboot, and not `start`.

**UPDATE**

You just need a simple url handler that returns a 200 response.  Could be something as simple as this in your `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /_ah/warmup                        # just serve simple, quick
    static_files: static/img/favicon.ico
    upload: static/img/favicon.ico
```

Or better, in your `urls.py`, point the url handler to a view like this:

```
(r'^_ah/warmup$', 'warmup'),
```

in views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def warmup():
  return HttpResponse('hello', content_type='text/plain')
```

Comment: I would like to config app engine with warmup, but at the moment I haven't found a tutorial with Django, that's why I want to have one instance always running in an easy way.

Comment: See update.  You just need a call to `/_ah/warmup` to return a 200 response.