# gcloud app engine instances being inactive after a while

Tags: google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

This is the app.yaml I define

> runtime: nodejs16 env: flex service: default env_variables:
> MONGO_USER: 'xxxxxx'   MONGO_PASS: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
> automatic_scaling:   min_num_instances: 3

This is the final configuration ,ignoring my config after deploying

> runtime: nodejs api_version: '1.0' env: flexible threadsafe: true
> env_variables:   MONGO_PASS: xxxxxx MONGO_USER: xxxxxx
> automatic_scaling:   cool_down_period: 120s   min_num_instances: 2
> max_num_instances: 20   cpu_utilization:
> target_utilization: 0.5 liveness_check:   initial_delay_sec: '300'   check_interval_sec: '30'   timeout_sec: '4'   failure_threshold: 4
> success_threshold: 2 readiness_check:   check_interval_sec: '5'
> timeout_sec: '4'   failure_threshold: 2   success_threshold: 2
> app_start_timeout_sec: '300'

I am trying to host a simple api server (nodejs,express,typescript)
but after a while the endpoint automatically becomes inactive when I ping from postman. Once I open the app engine dashboard and click on the instance, and make the api call again it works.

I tried this with both standard and flexible environment

I tried adding min_idle_instances:1 yet, it doesn't appear in the final config. (maybe it's only for standard env)

The docs say I should handle warmup request (for standard env), but I couldn't find a boilerplate on how to hanlde a warmup request

Answer (score 0):

To enable warmup requests, add the warmup element under the inbound_services directive in your app.yaml file as mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/configuring-warmup-requests#enabling_warmup_requests).

To handle the warm up request call to `/_ah/warmup` to return a 200 response.As described in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/configuring-warmup-requests#enabling_warmup_requests) You can also respond to warmup requests by using one of the following methods

> **Using a  servlet**
> The easiest way to provide warmup logic is to mark your own servlets as  in the web.xml configuration file.
>
> **Using a ServletContextListener**
> Al lows you to run custom logic before any of your servlets is first invoked either through a warmup request or a loading request.
>
> **Using a custom warmup servlet**
> Using a custom warmup servlet invokes the servlet's service method only during a warmup request rather than during loading requests.

You may also check this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63181239/18265570)